# Passing a unique value to all classes using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

The following code shows the flow I’m currently trying to implement within a WCF service. The service on startup calls the Bootstrapper class which uses Unity to register and resolve the required types. The Gateway class contains the public method which then kicks off the main flow of processing a message (there are many more levels to the code than is shown below).

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IGateway InitializeGateway()
    {

        IUnityContainer resolver = new UnityContainer();

        resolver.RegisterType<IGateway, Gateway>();
        resolver.RegisterType<ITranslator, Translator>();
        resolver.RegisterType<IFormatter, IFormatter>();

        return resolver.Resolve<IGateway>(); 
    }      

}

public class Gateway : IGateway
{

    private readonly ITranslator translator;
    private readonly IFormatter formatter;

    public Gateway(ITranslator translator, IFormatter formatter)
    {
        this.translator = translator;
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    public string ProcessMessage(string requestMessage)
    {
        // Create a new GUID for use in main flow for logging
        Guid messageGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        requestMessage = this.translator.TranslateMessage(requestMessage);

        requestMessage = this.formatter.FormatMessage(requestMessage);

        return requestMessage;
    }
}
```

Now what I’m trying to achieve is take the GUID (created for each message) and pass this down within the flow of the service such that each class has a reference to it for logging purposes.

I have tried to find a way of using DI and constructor injection but don’t know if this can be done as the GUID is created on receipt of a message by the gateway (after the bootstrapper call). What I’m trying to get away from is passing the GUID into each method as a parameter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're only resolving your Gateway once, then using that gateway to process several messages? If that's the case, then I don't see how DI via your IoC container can help. It's job is done by the time you start receiving messages. You're using the GUID to act as an identifier for each message. Why can you not encapsulate the GUID and requestMessage string into a Message class? That way any method that receives a message will have access to it's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own solution to this problem with DI, I would recommend you use the thread-static property [Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager.activityid.aspx) for this purpose.

Take a look at this article on [WCF End-To-End Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreal/archive/2009/03/21/wcf-end-to-end-tracing.aspx).